# Filter on Person with Lists.asmx and DataFormWebPart. 'This column type cannot be filtered'. (In 2010)

Tags: 2010, list-view, data-form-web-part, records-center

In SharePoint 2010 I want to display a document library view from a record-centre in another site collection and the best option seems to be Lists.asmx GetListItems and a DataFormWebPart.

I want to sort on Person columns so I set up a basic test with a vanilla document library in one site collection and a publishing site in another. I used Lists.asmx and a DataFormWebPart and switched-on Sorting by column.

If I attempt to filter on the ows_Editor column I receive the message:

"This column type cannot be filtered"

Is it possible to get this working?
If not, is there a better way of presenting data from a record centre?

Comment: This really depends on your available tools and comfor levels in what you are doing. How are you using Lists.asmx? Can you write custom code? Can you use jquery? This might help get a better answer.

Comment: I'm capable of coding, but I was asking from a standpoint of OOTB functionality which seems to be broken. This was a simple test of sorting on people.